# using python to send POST request

Tags: post, python-requests

I'm trying to send a POST request to a site (https://get.cbord.com/dartmouth/full/login.php) to log in. I think I'm running into issues with the format of the data I'm passing in, but truthfully I'm just getting started so I don't understand this very well. I tried deciphering the POST request using Chrome dev tools and this is what I came up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import sys

EMAIL = 'xxx'
PASSWORD = 'xxx'

LOGIN_URL = 'https://get.cbord.com/dartmouth/full/login.php'
FULL_URL = 'https://get.cbord.com/dartmouth/full/funds_home.php'

def main():

  # Start a session so we can have persistant cookies
  #session = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr})
  session = requests.session()

  # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
  login_data = {
    'username': EMAIL,
    'password': PASSWORD,
    'submit': 'Login',
  }

  # Authenticate
  r = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data)

  # Try accessing a page that requires you to be logged in
  r = session.get(FULL_URL)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The majority of the code is directly copy pasted from a response to a similar question. I guess I just don't understand how to figure out what the login_data dictionary should be.

Thanks for the help!

Pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I examined this page and found that there is one more parameter: formToken.
You can get its value from webpage source. It looks like these
    
So first you need to get https://get.cbord.com/dartmouth/full/login.php page

```
login_page = session.get(LOGIN_URL)
login_page_text = login_page.text
```

then parse the page to retrieve formToken value from it and finally authenticate

```
login_data = {
   'username': EMAIL,
   'password': PASSWORD,
   'submit': 'Login',
   'formToken': formToken_value
}
# Authenticate
r = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data)
```